# Python/Kivy - call class method immediately after object instantiation

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

With Kivy, I have created a custom button class, DefaultButton.

---

Python code:

```
class DefaultButton(Button):

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(DefaultButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       size_hint = (None, None)
       self.width = 200
       self.set_width()


   def set_width(self):
       if(self.texture_size[0] > self.width)
           self.width = self.texture_size[0]
       print(self.texture_size)
```

---

Kivy code:

```
<MainLayout>:
    size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint_y: None
        top: self.parent.top
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: 60
        DefaultButton:
            text: "really long string (longer than 200px)"
        DefaultButton:
            text: "short string" #less than 200px
```

---

In the `DefaultButton` class (python code), the method `set_width()` is intended to automatically set the width of the button to the text length but only if the text is longer than the set width. It checks the width of the texture (ie. the length of the button text) against the current width. If the texture is outside of the bounds of the button, it resizes it to the texture_width.

My first DefaultButton would resize to the length of its text, whereas the second button would not...

At the moment, the `set_width()` method prints '0' for each button's `texture_size` because `self.set_width` is being called within the `__init__` method, before the DefaultButton object is initialized. Is there any way to call `set_width()` on the current instance *immediately* after instantiation?

Comment: Your ``width = 200`` is setting a local variable that is not visible outside of ``__init__``, and which you do not ever use.  You'd need to assign to ``self.width`` if you want it to have any effect in ``set_width()``.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that was a typo

Comment: How did the first button resize? As your layout stands, both `DefaultButton` widgets will have exactly half of the width of the parent `BoxLayout`, and not custom sizes

Comment: I've just edited the code to set size_hint to (None, None). This was actually in my original code but I had cut it down for this question. Each button is resized to almost 0 width (they still appear as very small buttons).